# Invalid TextBox values gets reset by ComboBox's DataBinding

Tags: c#, validation, data-binding

**Situation:** A C# Windows Forms application with a TextBox and a ComboBox. AutoValidate is set to EnableAllowFocusChange.

The TextBox represents and is shown as a percentage value e.g. "10 %" which is stored as an int. Both input controls are data bound, the TextBox with a parsing and formatting ConvertEventHandler as well as a Validating CancelEventHandler.

When entering an invalid input like "abc" and leaving the control: My Validation is performed and fails (e.Cancel = true, ErrorProvider ..). And my parsing fails (e.Value stays "abc").

**Problem:** When I now change the value of the ComboBox and leave it (lost focus/perform validation) or do a ValidateChildren, my format function is called with the last valid percentage value and the wrong input is lost.

**Stacktrace:** The problem is triggered by a ReportPropertyChanged of the ComboBox and leads to Binding.PushData, FormatObject and OnFormat -> Which calls my format function with the original value.

I want my TextBox to stay invalid and no magical reset. What can I do to prevent a value reset? Or what did I do wrong?

Thanks!